# How to store large numbers?

Tags: c, arrays

I have to make a RSA signature (on a state machine) in `C` on a 32bit board. I am limited on memory so I can not store decimals in a vector or something like that.

The best thing would be if I could store bits and to have easy access to them; what storage method would be best?

I made this one:

```
#if (CPU_TYPE == CPU_TYPE_32)

typedef uint32_t word;
#define word_length 32
typedef struct BigNumber {
    word words[64];
} BigNumber;

#elif (CPU_TYPE == CPU_TYPE_16)

typedef uint16_t word;
#define word_length 16
typedef struct BigNumber {
    word words[128];
} BigNumber;

#else  
#error Unsupported CPU_TYPE  
#endif
```

This seems hard to use.  How can I simplify it?

Comment: If you cannot use existing libraries (GMP, MPFI, ...), you might want to check how those represent long integers. It's usually an array of unsigneds aligned with the platform.

Comment: I can not use any library , I think I  am going to try something with uint32 , Thank you!

Comment: *"I can not store decimals in a vector or something like that"* - Why? What's the limitation? Any specific size?

Comment: I have a RH850 board( https://www.renesas.com/en-us/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/rh850/softtools.html )  and this is why the memory is limited and the hole algorithm will be structured on a state machine , this is why I should pay more attention on not losing data.

Comment: I made this this structure do you have any better ideas? if (CPU_TYPE == CPU_TYPE_32)
 typedef uint32_t word;
 #define word_length 32
 typedef struct BigNumber {
  word words[64];
 } BigNumber;
#elif (CPU_TYPE == CPU_TYPE_16)
 typedef uint16_t word;
 #define word_length 16
 typedef struct BigNumber {
  word words[128];
 } BigNumber;
#else  
 #error Unsupported CPU_TYPE  
#endif

Answer (score 4):

You may simply use the BigNumber API from OpenSSL. You can find the full API [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/bn.html).

And, you can use this code sample as a start:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  static const char num1[] = "18446744073709551616";
  static const char num2[] = "36893488147419103232";

  BIGNUM *bn1 = NULL;
  BIGNUM *bn2 = NULL;
  BN_CTX *ctx = BN_CTX_new();

  BN_dec2bn(&bn1, num1); // convert the string to BIGNUM
  BN_dec2bn(&bn2, num2);

  BN_add(bn1, bn1, bn2); // bn1 = bn1 + bn2

  char *result_str = BN_bn2dec(bn1);  // convert the BIGNUM back to string
  printf("%s + %s = %s\n", num1, num2, result_str);
  OPENSSL_free(result_str);

  BN_free(bn1);
  BN_free(bn2);
  BN_CTX_free(ctx);

  return 0;
}
```

Compile it with:

```
#> gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -o sample sample.c -lcrypto
```

You should get something like this when executing it:

```
18446744073709551616 + 36893488147419103232 = 55340232221128654848
```

Comment: Thank you , but I couldn't not use any library  because of memory limitations , I used that method that I posted in question , but I still live this question unanswered , in case of a better  solution , that will help someone else .

Comment: You can also look at [mbed TLS](https://tls.mbed.org/) is a very similar library to OpenSSL specifically used in embedded systems. The problem with your "memory limitation" is that you never told precisely how strict they were.